# How to mod-rewrite the url with custom extension

Tags: mod-rewrite, seo, subdomain, file-extension

I need to change the pattern of my url from the normal path into a subdomain. I tried write the .htaccess but it's not work.

`http://hello.com/sos/article.php?id=1&title=this-is-a-title.php`

From the url above I want to:

1. Change the pattern to call the page so I remove `sos` before the domain as a subdomain. So I'd got `http://sos.hello.com/`
2. I need the variable to be replaced with forward slash and suffixed with `.sos`. As the story is about warning : `article/1/this-is-a-title.sos`

I wish I could have something like this:
`http://sos.hello.com/article/1/this-is-a-title.sos`

So I wrote :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.sos$ /article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

And guess what! It's not work. Please point me out. What I've done wrong???

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer after several tries:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hello.com
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sos/$ http://sos.hello.com/mypage.php
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.sos$ /article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

save as `.htaccess` to the subdomain directory